# Unable to play HEVC / x265 video in VLC with display set to 3840x2160 after update to Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: drivers, video, vlc, nvidia-geforce

I updated to 22.04 last week.
I have a GF 660 and I am running the nvidia 470 drivers.
I have tried purging and re-installing nvidia drivers already.

The following are the symptoms:

1. When display is set to 1080p, HEVC videos will playback in VLC with "Automatic" video output.
2. When display is set to 2160p, HEVC videos will playback in VLC only with "X11" video output (no OpenGL etc).
3. When display is set to 2160p, AVC / x264 will playback in VLC with "Automatic" video output.

Any help appreciated, especially where to find nvidia driver's logs to dig into that.

Comment: I think it is a VLC issue. Have you looked at this site that has some troubleshooting tips? https://www.stellarinfo.com/blog/6-methods-to-play-4k-ultra-hd-video-in-vlc-player/

Comment: Yes, I am pretty sure it's drivers at this point.